# Multi-language Support and Conctact Form

Tags: php, forms, multilingual, contacts

I'm using this a multi-language php script to translate my static html pages. 
I'm using exactly this one:http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html

```
<?php echo $lang['Text Here']; ?>
```

The problem is that I can't make it work with my contact form:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "test@gmail.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'New Visitor of website ...'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    } 

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone       = filter_var($_POST["userPhone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Phone)) //check entered data is numbers
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Only numbers allowed in phone field'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

I already included the languages php file in the contact form and this is not working:

```
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => echo $lang['Text Here'];));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my local server running your PHP script and debugged with my Netbeans IDE. I don't see any bugs in your script so far. Can you paste your source codes for your contact form?

Comment: This is the contact form i'm using: http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form 

Just wanted the error outputs to be translated.